# Jenkins docker container simply hangs and never executes steps

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm trying to run a Python image in Jenkins to perform a series of unit tests with pytest, but I'm getting some strange behavior with Docker.

My Jenkinsfile pipeline is

```
  agent {
      docker { image 'python:3.6-jessie' }
    }

    stages {
      stage('Run tests') {
        steps {
            withCredentials([
                string(credentialsId: 'a-secret', variable: 'A_SECRET')
            {

              sh label: "Install dependencies", script: 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
              sh label: 'Execute tests', script: "pytest mytests.py"
            }
     }
  }
}
```

However, when I run the pipeline, Docker appears to be executing a very long instruction (with significantly more `-e` environment variables than I defined as credentials?), followed by `cat`.

The build then simply hangs and never finishes:

```
         Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
            $ docker run -t -d -u 996:994 
    -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject 
    -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject:rw,z
    -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject@tmp:rw,z 
-e ******** -e ******** python:3.6-jessie cat
```

When I SSH into my instance and run `docker ps`, I see

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
240d00459d92        python:3.6-jessie   "cat"               About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       kind_wright
```

Why is Jenkins running `cat`? Why does Jenkins say I am not running inside a container, when it has clearly created a container for me? And most importantly, why are my `pip install -r requirements` and other steps not executing?

Comment: Is it related to `pytest` at all? What happens if you replace the shell commands with `echo hello world`?

Comment: @hoefling it was not- check my answer- I found the solution after a night of research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured this out. If you have empty global environment variables in your Jenkins configuration, it appears that you'll get a malformed `docker run` command since Jenkins will write the command, with your empty string environment variable, as `docker run -e some_env_var=some_value -e = ...`

This will cause the container to simply hang.

A telltale sign that this is happening is you'll get the error message:

```
invalid argument "=" for "-e, --env" flag: invalid environment variable: =
```

This is initially difficult to diagnose since Jenkins (rightfully) hides your actual credentials with ***, so the empty environment strings do not show up as empty.

You need to check your Jenkins global configuration and make sure you don't have any empty environment variables accidentally defined:

[image]

If these exist, you need to delete them and rerun.

Comment: We saw this exact same problem. One thing to note is that in our case, that "telltale sign" didn't exist... the container just hung as described in the original post. We did indeed though have an empty environment variable, as Yu Chen described, and deleting that fixed the problem. Thanks, Yu Chen!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case, using a Windows docker environment as Jenkins agent, but with a hanging "bat" call just the same when trying to run my pipeline using a docker image. Trying to figure out where the problem is (as I didn't get any hints whatsoever), I stumbled upon this question's answer here which gave me a push in the right direction.

Turned out the problem was not with environment variables, but with the name of the jenkins job: I had spaces in the name of the job (e.g. "My Jenkins Job"), which probably weren't properly escaped when dealing with the container. When I changed that (e.g. to "My-Jenkins-Job"), everything worked fine. So it might be a similar cause (values empty or at least not as expected), but for a different reason.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by appending the `-u root` parameter to the `args`:

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'alpine/k8s:1.27.4'
        args "-u root"
    }
}
```

I know using `root` might not be a good idea, but it works and I think it's okay for my CI environment.